# Weird square brush bug while sculpting!

Tags: sculpting

Hi I'm fairly new to 3D and have basic understanding of most of the things blender offer!
Recently I ran into a bug where the sculpting brush turns into a big square like artifact when it comes to contact to a mesh!

[image: when brush is not in contact to mesh]

[image: when brush comes to contact]

The issue persists on all the objects in the scene, and actually resolves when I copy the object to a new blend.
I want to know what happened so that I can avoid issues like this in future.

I did try to run on different blender builds but the issue persisted.

Comment: also it freezes when it becomes square!

Comment: What is your GPU model?

Comment: It's gtx 1050ti